# vagrant unable to mount shared folders

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/root/shared", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
end
```

Here's the output I get when I run it:

https://pastebin.com/mXiv2EPw/?e=1

In particular, there's this:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o dmode=777,fmode=666,uid=1000,gid=1000 root_shared /root/shared

The error output from the command was:

: No such file or directory
```

I did `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` and got this:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-vbguest' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vbguest (0.13.0)'!
```

I did `vagrant vbguest` (apparently the VM needs to be running for `vagrant vbguest` to run):

```
[default] GuestAdditions 5.1.16 running --- OK.
```

I've also encountered this error with scotch/box:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/root/shared", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
end
```

I'm running laravel/homestead v2.0.0, VirtualBox 5.1.16 r113841 (Qt5.6.2) and Vagrant 1.9.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the latest version of Virtualbox (5.1.18) fixed this. Quoting https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog ,

> - Shared Folders: fixed case insensitive filename access (5.1.16    regression; Windows guests only; bug
>     [#16549](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16549))
> - Shared Folders: fixed    access to long pathes (5.1.16 regression; Windows guests only; bugs
>     [#14651](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14651),
>     [#16564](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16564))